# Python/Numpy: Combining boolean masks by row in 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, masking

I have a 2D numpy array of boolean masks with n rows where each row is an array of m masks.

```
maskArr = [
            [[True, False, True, False], [True, True, False, True], [True, True, False, True]],
            [[False, True, False, True], [False, True, True, True], [True, True, False, True]],
            [[True, False, True, False], [True, True, False, True], [True, True, False, True]],
            [[False, True, False, True], [False, True, True, True], [True, True, False, True]],
            [[True, False, True, False], [True, True, False, True], [True, True, False, True]],
            [[False, True, False, True], [False, True, True, True], [True, True, False, True]]
          ]
```

Is there a way to vectorize the combining of mask arrays in each row to get the following result?

```
combinedMaskArr = [
                    [True, False, False, False],
                    [False, True, False, True],
                    [True, False, False, False],
                    [False, True, False, True],
                    [True, False, False, False],
                    [False, True, False, True]
                  ]
```

Thank you for any guidance or suggestions in advance.

Comment: seems you want to apply "AND" operations on each triplet of corresponding values. Look for "all" in numpy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to testing whether all elements are true along a specific axis. Use [`np.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html)

```
np.all(maskArr, axis=1)
```

Output

```
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True]])
```