# Python/Numpy: Combining boolean masks by row in grouped columns in multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have a 3D boolean array (a 2D numpy array of boolean mask arrays) with `r` rows and `c` cols. In the example below the array shape is (3, 6, 2); 3 rows and 6 columns, where each column contains 2 elements.

```
maskArr = np.array([
                     [[True, False], [True, True], [True, True], [True, True], [True, True], [True, True]],
                     [[False, True], [False, True], [True, True], [False, True], [True, True], [True, True]],
                     [[True, False], [True, True], [True, True], [True, True], [True, True], [True, True]],
                  ])

           # If n=2:  |<-   AND   these 2 cols  ->|<-   AND   these 2 cols  ->|<-   AND   these 2 cols  ->|

           # If n=3:  |<-----       AND  these 3 cols    ----->|<-----      AND   these 3 cols     ----->|
```

I know I can use `np.all(maskArr, axis=1)` to `and` together **all** the mask arrays in each row [as in previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703012/python-numpy-combining-boolean-masks-by-row-in-2d-array), but instead I would like to `and` together the boolean arrays in each row in increments of `n` columns.

So if we start with 6 columns, as above, and `n=2`, I would like to apply the equivalent of `np.all` on every 2 columns for an end result of 3 columns, where:

1. The first column of the result array equals the rows of the first (2) columns of the original array `AND`ed together - `result[:,0] = np.all(maskArr[:,0:1], axis=1)`
2. The second column of the result array equals the rows of the second (2) columns of the original array `AND`ed together. - `result[:,1] = np.all(maskArr[:,2:3], axis=1)`
3. And the third column of the result array equals the rows of the last (2) columns of the original array `AND`ed together. - `result[:,2] = np.all(maskArr[:,4:5], axis=1)`

Is there a way to use `np.all` (or another vectorized approach) to get this result?

**Expected result** with `n=2`:

```
>>>    np.array([
                     [[True, False], [True, True], [True, True]],
                     [[False, True], [False, True], [True, True]],
                     [[True, False], [True, True], [True, True]],
               ])
```

Note: The array I'm working with is extremely large so I'm looking for a vectorized approach to minimize performance impact. The actual boolean arrays can be thousands of elements long.

I've tried:

```
n = 2
c = len(maskArr[0])      ## c = 6  (number of columns)
nResultColumns = int(c / n)   ## nResultColumns = 3

combinedMaskArr = [np.all(maskArr[:,i*n:i*n+n], axis=1) for i in range(nResultColumns)]
```

which gives me:

```
>>>  [
         array([[True, False], [False, True], [True, False]]), 
         array([[True, True], [False, True], [True, True]]), 
         array([[True, True], [True, True], [True, True]])
     ]
```

The output above is not the expected format or values.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to get to the expected result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're exactly asking, sorry.

Comment: @orlp does that new intro help clarify?

Comment: Well, you say you have a 2D array but you have a 3D array, so I'm still confused.

Comment: My mistake, you're right. It now says 3D array

Comment: The problem is that your problem description doesn't make any sense then. What is a column, what is a row?

Comment: You can look at it as a 2D array of boolean mask arrays or a 3D boolean array. The shape of the example array is (3, 6, 2) so there are 3 rows and 6 columns, where each column has 2 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works, if I understood your problem correctly.

```
n = 2
cols = mask_arr.shape[1]
chunks = math.ceil(cols / n)
groups = np.array_split(np.swapaxes(mask_arr, 0, 1), chunks)
combined = np.array([np.all(g, axis=0) for g in groups])
result = np.swapaxes(combined, 0, 1)
```

If `cols` is divisible by `n`, I think this works:

```
n = 2
rows, cols = mask_arr.shape[0:2]
result = np.all(mask_arr.reshape(rows, cols // n, n, -1), axis=2)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer does work. I have to ask, though - do you know if there is a way to do this completely vectorized without a list comprehension?

Comment: @CraigNathan I think so, but only if the number of columns is divisible by `n`.

Comment: Yes the number of columns will always be divisible by `n`

Comment: @CraigNathan Then it's simpler, see my updated answer.

Comment: What does the `2` represent in the last argument of `reshape`? Is that the length of each boolean array?

Comment: @CraigNathan Oh yes, it is, you can replace it with `-1` to automatically derive that size.